# Inserting code in forums

Tags: asp.net

If we insert code in asp.net forums we have to put any additional tags in code for displaying??because so many sides my code is not coming in questions but if we are going to edit question the code is coming

Comment: This really depends on the forum your using

Comment: i think we have to put all complete tage,,means closing tags also,not partial codind

Comment: I don't think so ... see the update to my answer below.  Upvote/answer flagging is appreciated if correct.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the forum help ... most forums allow some type of inline code to be defined in blocks, such as the 'Code Sample' pre tags here in SO:

```
void main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return;
}
```

If you're specifically talking about Microsoft's ASP.NET forum, click the code button (looks like this:  [alt text http://forums.asp.net/tiny_mce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/sourcecode/images/code.gif](http://forums.asp.net/tiny_mce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/sourcecode/images/code.gif)) and paste your code into the window that pops up.  The site will do all the HTML tag translation for you.

Comment: i think we have to put all complete tage,,means closing tags also,not partial codind

Comment: i did nt get you  ,,pre tags here in SO: means